# Proof of a Vector Identity Using Index Notation

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

I'm having a hard time proving this vector identity:

> $$(A \cdot (B \times C))D = (C \cdot D)(A \times B) + (A \cdot D)(B \times C) + (B \cdot D)(C \times A)$$

Please note: I was hoping to prove this using index notation. Not any other math methods. I mean, by using index notation with Kronecker Delta or Epsilon symbols.

Could someone help me about this? I have no idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Linear Independent Case**

$1)$ If $A$, $B$, and $C$ are three independent vectors then $A \times B$, $B \times C$, and $C \times A$ are also independent so they can form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$. So we can write any vector as a linear combination of them.

$2)$ According to step $(1)$ we have

$$(A \cdot (B \times C))D = \alpha (A \times B) + \beta (B \times C) + \gamma (C \times A)$$

where $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ are unknown coefficients. If we dot product with $A$, $B$, and $C$, respectively, we can get

$$\eqalign{
  & \left( {A \cdot (B \times C)} \right)\left( {A\cdot D} \right) = \beta A\cdot (B \times C)  \cr 
  & \left( {A \cdot (B \times C)} \right)\left( {B \cdot D} \right) = \gamma B \cdot (C \times A)  \cr 
  & \left( {A \cdot (B \times C)} \right)\left( {C \cdot D} \right) = \alpha C \cdot (A \times B) \cr} $$

$3)$ We note that

$$A \cdot (B \times C) = B \cdot (C \times A) = C \cdot (A \times B)$$

$4)$ We finally conclude that
$$\eqalign{
  & \alpha  = C \cdot D  \cr 
  & \beta  = A \cdot D  \cr 
  & \gamma  = B \cdot D \cr} $$

**Linear Dependent Case**

Consider the case when  the vectors $A$, $B$, and $C$ are linearly dependent and hence they cannot form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$. This means that there exists real numbers $a$ and $b$ not both zero such that
$A = aB + bC$
will hold. This will lead to $(A \cdot (B \times C))=0$ and turns our equation into a trivial identity $0=0$.

Comment: Very good. I have added a brief answer to cover the case of lineard dependence.

Comment: @user254665: If $A$, $B$, and $C$ are linearly dependent then $A \cdot (B \times C)=0$. :)

Comment: @H.R. Your comment came in while I was typing my answer so I didn't see it  .You can rely on me for the most complicated solution.Of  course your identity 3)  takes  care of  the dependent case immediately but I'm leaving my answer up anyway. It's not meant as a criticism.

Comment: Could you please do it by index notation? Thank you!

Comment: @H.R. A, B, C can be linearly dependent, and the identity also holds. If that's the case, your step 1 and 2 cannot apply. How should I deal with that?

Comment: @Tmi...: The index notation just makes the computations easier but it cannot change the logic behind a question! In problems that require direct computation index notation can help you to do the arithmetic fast and easy. However, I cannot see that this problem can be solved by direct computation! It needs some logic behind. :) The other answer take care of this case. :)

Comment: @Tmi...: I knew what you meant by index notation! See my comment above. :)

Comment: @H.R. Thank you! You are right. The logic is the same. But I just saw someone proved it by index notation in a much shorter way without any linear dependency assumption. It's much better than this by just using the property of Levi Civita Symbol...

Comment: @Tmi...: I will be happy if you post this solution as an answer so that we can learn from it! :)

Comment: @H.R. Sorry I don't know how to type the Latex here. Since I guess you have very good background in index notation. I'm willing to describe the basic idea, and I believe you could get it. So, by writing the equation using index notation. On the LHS, you will have 1 epsilon symbol, A, B, C, and D, and 4 indices. On the RHS, for each term, you will have the same number of symbols and indices. Since it's in R3, there will be at least one index is the same with one of the other 3. So, using the property of epsilon symbol, which is epsilon(i,i,j)=0, and a simple permutation test. We could prove it.

Comment: @H.R. I guess that's the power of index notation. We could just remember the properties of epsilon symbol, delta symbol and so on, to derive some fairly complex math equations without thinking about the problem from linear algebra perspective. If we have to think about the problem from linear algebra logic, and then write it by index notation just as a different form of writing style, I couldn't see the meaning of index notation.

Comment: @Tmi...: I will try to understand and add the solution in index notation. :)

Comment: @Tmi...: Did you get RHS from the LHS or vice versa? :)

Comment: @H.R. My friend wrote the RHS and LHS independently and proved it.

Comment: @H.R. It's like: LHS = E(ijk).Ai.Bj.Ck.Dm, and there will be at most 3 indices there, so when m = i, m = j, m = k ... , the LHS would be, respectively, blablabla. Same idea for RHS, it can be proved this way.

Comment: @H.R. With the property epsilon(i,i,j)=0, the permutation is not lengthy, many of the possibilities are zeros.

Comment: @H.R. I guess it's just like the row-reduce-echelon-form method. If every time we have to think of a problem from the logic of system of equations, and then Guass-elimination, and then apply RREF, it really defeats the purpose of using this method.

Comment: @Tmi...: I got you now! I think this not proving but the people call it though! :) I call this justifying! :) Suppose that you didn't know the equality. How would you discover such a thing will hold? I don't like this kind of proving really! :) It is blind computation!

Comment: @H.R sorry. Maybe I didn't express it in the right way. My friend said it is designed by understanding and precisely matching the principle of another method. But after it's designed and proved. You can just use it without thinking about the problem from the old way. And it could make process easier for complex problem. Sorry if I said anything inappropriate. I really appreciate your help in the first place:)

Comment: @Tmi...: Nope you didn't! :) You have written down the LHS and RHS and investigated the all cases. This is brute force and also you need **both** RHS and LHS for this kind of proof. I prefer to start from one side and reach to the other side. :)

Comment: @Tmi...: Take a look at [my post here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1545710/how-to-prove-a-times-b-otimes-c-b-times-c-otimes-a-c-times-a-ot). Just for You and also my curiosity! :)

Comment: @Tmi...: Also I edited the answer above to include the linear dependent case as easy as possible. :)

Comment: @H.R. Your proof was beautiful up there! It's very inspiring. Thank you!

Comment: @Tmi...: You are welcome! :) You can vote it up! :) Also, try complete my proof there. :)

Comment: @H.R. I will when I have 15 points :) Now the system doesn't allow me to up vote an answer :(

Comment: @Tmi...: You will get that score soon! :) Take a look at [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1545710/how-to-prove-a-times-b-otimes-c-b-times-c-otimes-a-c-times-a-ot). I added a nice proof in the answers. :) Hope you like it.

Answer (score 1):

H.R. has given the answer for the case when $A,B,C$ are linearly independent. In $\mathbb{R}^3$ if $A,B,C$ are linearly dependent, then:

$(1).$ If $B,C$ are linearly dependent then $A,B,C$ are co-linear and $0=A\times B=B\times C=C\times A$.

$(2).$ If $B,C$ are linearly independent, let $A+A'=A''$ be linearly independent of $B,C$  and write the equations for linearly independent $A'',B,C$ and for linearly independent $A',B,C$ and subtract them.

Comment: Could you please show me how to use index notation to prove this identity?

Comment: @Timi. $(a,b,c)\cdot (a',b',c')=a a'+b b'+c c')$ and $(a,b,c)\times (a',b',c')=(b c'-c b',c a'-a c',a b'-a' b)$. Brute force will now work after a great deal of writing. I have decided to show how to reduce this  task by posting a second answer about it.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is a request to show this using index notation (i.e. in terms of co-ordinates), observe that if the equation holds for each of $A_1,A_2,$ and $A_3$  then it holds for any linear combination of $A_1,A_2,A_3$, and we make a similar observation regarding $B, C$ and $D$ . Since $(u,v,w)\cdot (u',v',w')=(u u',v v',w w')$ and $(u,v,w)\times (u',v',w')=(v w'-v' w,w v'-w' v,u v'-u'v)$, writing out the whole equation would give a huge formula which would eventually reduce to $0=0$ if you are a computer. But using the observation, we can see that it  suffices to verify the equation when  $$\{A,B,C,D\} \subset \{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}.$$ This gives 81 cases to check but we can reduce much further by observing that  the equation holds for any $A,B,C,D$ iff it holds for $$f(A),f(B),f(C),f(D)$$ $$ \text { and for } f(f(A)),f(f(B)),f(f(C)),f(f(D))$$ $$\text {where }  f(x,y,z)=(y,z,x)$$ because $f$ will just permute the co-ordinates, on both sides ot the equation, in the same way. So we need only to consider $A=(1,0,0)$.This gives 27 cases. Further if $(A=B)\lor (B=C )\lor (C=A)$  then the original equation is easily verified,because  of the properties $U\times V=-V\times U$ and $U\times U=0$ for any vectors $U,V$.Still further,these properties show that the original equation holds iff it holds when we interchange $B$ with $C$. So it suffices  to consider $$A=(1,0,0), B=(0,1,0),C=(0,0,1).$$ At this point we have $$(A\times B=C)\land (B\times C=A)\land (C\times A=B)$$  $$\text {and } (A\cdot (B\times C)D=(A\cdot A)D=D.$$ Now we can handle all $D$ at once, by confirming that $$D=(C\cdot D)C+(A\cdot D)A+(B\cdot D)B$$ $$\text {when } A=(1,0,0),B=(0,1,0),C=(0,0,1).$$ Which should be obvious.